# Finding the right line and get data out of it

Tags: php, json

I have a file that contains lines that look like this:

> {"name":"RandomName1","level":20,"class":"something","experience":2688746894},"account":{"name":"RandomAcc1","challenges":{"total":0}}},{"online":false,"rank":172,"dead":false,"character":
>
> {"name":"RandomName2","level":21,"class":"something","experience":2687863942},"account":{"name":"RandomAcc2","challenges":{"total":0}}},{"online":false,"rank":173,"dead":false,"character":
>
> {"name":"RandomAcc3","level":22,"class":"something","experience":2687280914},"account":{"name":"RandomAcc3","challenges":{"total":0}}},{"online":false,"rank":174,"dead":false,"character":

I want to search for a name, for example "RandomAcc3", if the name is found, check the "online" status in that line and extract that into a boolean. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?

Comment: Is this the whole file, or just part of it?  It looks like JSON, but not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the file, json_decode into an array, fetch the array (`foreach`) and check if the current subelement contains the string (`substr`/`preg_match`). if so, you'll consider/return the "online" element. hope you have a bit of coding skills to write it yourself, otherwise use codeacademy, not stackoverflow

Comment: Never heard of json_decode before but that was the key to the answer. Thanks a lot, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($filepath);
preg_match('/"name":"RandomAcc3"(.*)"online":([a-z]+)/i', $fileContent, $matches);
$onlineStatus = ($matches[2] == 'true');
```